# get list of archived chats in pyrogram

Tags: python, telethon, pyrogram, telegram-api

How can I get list of archived chats with pyrogram? or with any other python library?

I have searched a lot in documentation and goolge, couldn't find anything.

looks like not implemented in pyrogram.

---------------------------------------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For telethon use [`get_dialogs`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.get_dialogs)(archived=True).

For pyrogram it's not implements in native get_dialogs, use the [raw](https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/advanced-usage) api [messages.getDialog](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/messages/get-dialogs) with folder_id=1. copy the library [source code](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/blob/efac17198b5fcaec1c2628c4bba0c288a4d617d4/pyrogram/methods/chats/get_dialogs.py#L26-L104) of get_dialogs, and re-implement it with said parameter.